# Task with path 'build' not found in root project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multiproject and after the last subproject is built, I'd like to process all jars. 
Therefore I created a task in the root-project:

```
task install(dependsOn: 'build', type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        println "exec install task"
    }
}
```

Upon calling `./gradlew install` in the root directory, I'm facing this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':install'.
> Task with path 'build' not found in root project 'foo'.
```

However, calling `./gradlew tasks` shows me these tasks:

```
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
...
```

How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume, that your root project organizes the build, but does not define build action taken by itself. The `build` task is often defined by language plugins (in most cases via `apply plugin: 'java'`), but if your root project does not use any of them, it won't have a `build` task.

The description of the help task `tasks`, which you used, [says](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_tasks):

> Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'projectReports' **(some of the displayed tasks may belong to subprojects)**.

The help task followes the same logic as the task activation via the command line. You can provide a task name and any task with the name in any subproject will be executed (thats why `gradle build` works).

But if you define a `dependsOn` dependency, the given string is evaluated as task path for a single task. Since each task name can only be used once in a project, the name is unique for tasks in the root project, but many tasks could be found, if subprojects would be considered. Therefor, one can use the syntax `:<projectName>:<taskName>` to identify tasks in subprojects.

Now, let's face your specific problem: If the `install` task should depend on the `build` task of one single subproject, you could use `dependsOn ':<mySubproject>:build'`. But I assume you want the `install` task to depend on each subproject `build` task, so I'd like to propose this approach:

```
task install(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn subprojects*.tasks*.findByName('build').minus(null)
    doLast {
        println "exec install task"
    }
}
```

This way, for each registered subproject, `findByName('build')` is called and the result (the found task or `null`) is put into a list, which is then used as task dependency list. I added the `.minus(null)` part to remove `null` entries from the list, because I am not sure how Gradle handles such entries in a dependency collection. If you are sure, that each subproject provides a `build` task, you can use `getByName('build')`, too.

**EDIT:** OP found the optionally recursive `getTasksByName` method, which suits this case even better than iterating over all subprojects manually:

```
dependsOn getTasksByName('build', true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I'll give it a try as soon as possible. Will `dependsOn subprojects*.findByName('build').minus(null)` result in only one call to `install`? If I have subproject A, B and C, `install` should run exactly once after the last `build` of all subprojects finished.

Comment: Yes, every task is only executed once. If one depends on multiple other tasks, it will be executed after all these tasks are done. If you would be for 100% sure, that the `build` task of subproject C will __always__ be the last one, you could use `dependsOn ':projectC:build'`, but I would recommend to depend on each of the tasks and let Gradle figure out the dependency tree by itself. For three projects you could also define the dependencies manually via `dependsOn ':projectA:build', ':projectB:build', ':projectC:build'`.

Comment: I finally found the time to try out your solution. Unfortunately `findByName` didn't seem to work but this line of code does what I expect: `dependsOn subprojects*.getTasksByName("build", true)`. Feel free to update your solution and I'm happy to accept it as such. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, I immediately found my mistake: `findByName` is a method of the `TaskContainer` class and not of the `project` class, so I need to access the `TaskContainer` instance first: `dependsOn subprojects*.tasks*.findByName('build').minus(null)`. However, the method you found, seems to suit the problem even better, but you can call it directly on the root project, since it provides recursive task search. Therefor, `dependsOn getTasksByName('build', true)` should also work.